# C++ Creating array of derived classes of two separate abstract classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

It might be a stupid question but I had to ask anyway. I have 2 separate abstract classes: **Character** and **Enemy**. **Barbarian** and **Necromancer** are derived from **Character**, **Skeleton** and **Devil** are derived from **Enemy.** My question is can I create an array of the derivations of both **Character** and **Enemy**. Could I create another class lets say **Entity** like this:

```
class Entity : public Character, public Enemy {};
```

Then I would create an array of pointers to **Enemy**.

Can I do this somehow then:

```
Entity* p = new Barbarian;
```

Also if this is possible I suppose I would need a virtual destructor. How can I define this?

EDIT: A foolish mistake of mine, the inheritance should be other way around and the question is can it be done as that?

Comment: Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. Since e.g. `Barbarian` doesn't inherit from `Entity` it's not an `Entity` and your initialization of `p` is incorrect.

Comment: Wouldn't an enemy be a character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the other way around. You should create an Entity abstract class. Character and Enemy should inherit the entity class.

```
class Character : public Entity

class Enemy : public Entity
```

Everything else you mentioned is fine. You would need to create an Array of the Entity class, and for each Entity, you can say `ent = new Barbarian()` or something like that.

Comment: `public Entity` sounds like a great name for a nerdcore rap act.

Comment: Also would it be okay if I leave the Entity class empty besides the virtual destructor.

Comment: When you make an array of an Abstract Base class (Entity), it implies that you will use common functionality that is the same across ALL derived classes. For example, let's say you want ALL the entities to be able to have some kind of AI functionality. The Entity class could have some function called `ent->startAI()`, which ALL derived classes must implement. (silly example, but this is to get the point across)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it that way. With

```
class Entity : public Character, public Enemy {}
```

an `Entity` would always be both a `Character` and an `Enemy` the same time, but it could not be one (or more) of the subclasses like `Barbarian`.

So `Entity* p = new Barbarian;` will not work.

To achieve what you want, introduce `Entity` as a common base class for `Character` and `Enemy`:

```
class Entity {};
class Character : public Entity {};
class Barbarian : public Character {};
...
class Enemy : public Entity {};
...
std::vector<Entity*> e;
Barbarian *b = new Barbarian();
e.push_back(b);
```

Comment: Note that is still possible without `Enemy` and `Character` sharing a common base class, though notably less trivial, and comes for a price.

Comment: How can I do it without sharing the same base class?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, probably, is do it in reverse:

```
struct Entity {
    virtual ~Entity = default;
};
struct Enemy: Entity {};
struct Character: Entity {};
```

Then there won't be problems with casting a pointer to any creature to an `Entity *`.

Comment: There is no need to cast any derived pointers to `Entity *`.  An `Enemy` *is* an `Entity`.  A `Character` *is* an `Entity`.

Comment: I mean _upcasting_.